# C# MVC 4 API - Three functions throwing errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create a API using MVC4 with C#.  I'm having issues with a few of my commands.  I keep getting this error: "The best overloaded match for 'API.Controllers.EmployeesController.GetDepartment(int)' has some invalid arguments."  Below is my code.  I get the error on three different lines that call similar functions.  The value that is being sent to the functions has the posibility of being null.

```
public List<Models.Position> GetPositions(int EmployeeID)
    {
        var positions = from position in _context.tbl_positions
                        where position.people_ID == EmployeeID
                        select new Models.Position
                        {
                            PositionID = position.id
                            ,Department = position.dept_ID == null ? string.Empty : GetDepartment(position.dept_ID)
                            ,JobTitle = position.title
                            ,Building = position.location_ID == null ? string.Empty : GetBuilding(position.location_ID)
                            ,Room = position.room
                            ,Phone = position.public3 == null ? string.Empty : "000-111-" + position.public3
                            ,Fax = position.fax3 == null ? string.Empty : "000-111-" + position.fax3
                            ,College = position.college_ID == null ? string.Empty ? GetCollege(position.college_ID)
                        };

        return positions.ToList();
    }

    public string GetDepartment(int DeptId)
    {
        var department = (from departments in _context.tbl_departments
                          where departments.ID == DeptId
                          select departments.dept).SingleOrDefault();

        return department;
    }

    public string GetBuilding(int BID)
    {
        var building = (from buildings in _context.tbl_locations
                          where buildings.id == BID
                          select buildings.Name).FirstOrDefault();

        return building;
    }

    public string GetCollege(int CID)
    {
        var college = (from colleges in _context.tbl_colleges
                          where colleges.id == CID
                          select colleges.college).SingleOrDefault();

        return college;
    }
```

Comment: What are the types of objects you're passing in? Looks like location_ID, college_ID, and dept_ID aren't int's.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your question explains it all:

> The value that is being sent to the functions has the posibility of
>   being null.

Your problem is that you are passing a nullable int to a method that expects an int. Either change the signature of your method to:

```
public string GetDepartment(int? departmentId)
```

or change your call to GetDepartment to:

```
string department = GetDepartment(departmentId.Value);
```

Of course, whichever you choose, make sure to check the argument for a null value before you attempt to reference it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps passing in a `int?` or `Nullable<int>`? Try `position.college_ID.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `dept_ID` (+1 to Scott comment) ?

What I can say just by looking to your code is that `dept_ID` is a reference type for sure (so definitely not an `int` which is a value type). Indeed you are doing a check in the code to see if `dept_id` is `null` (however if `dept_ID` was truly an `int` it won't compile anyway, as it is not possible to check a value type against `null`).

So `dept_ID` is either a `Nullable<int>` (syntactic sugar: `int?`) which would make sense ... and it that case Max answer will work just fine ... or `dept_id` is another reference type (a class for example), and in that case we will need the type declaration to see how to go around this.

In any way this is `dept_ID` is for sure not an int so it makes sense that you get the error "invalid arguments" as `GetDepartment` except an `int` argument but you are giving it something that is not an int.

Similarly, the error will also be present for your call to `GetCollege` and `GetBuilding`, both expecting `int` value type as an argument but getting a reference type which is not an `int`.

Hope that helps !